# Numpy Mask transparency matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I realeased a mask with this.

```
z=pp[y,x,_mapa_]
nr, nc = z.shape
z[:nr//3, :nc//8] = np.nan
```

but python return this warning.

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py:778: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
  return umath.absolute(a) * self.tolerance >= umath.absolute(b)
```

I am searching the form that mask values > 998 and that point is transparency to matplotlib and masking when calc max and min.

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: Hello. The code UP give me this error. I dont know why

Comment: what is pp,y,x,_mapa_? what objects are they? what dtype, what shape, etc? (at the end, you suddenly say something about values>998, and nowhere else you mention any 998?

Comment: Sorry this question is not a good question. I think that this warnings is because I z=np.divide(pp[y,x,_mapa_], 100)  before mask.